# getting wrong value checkbox jQuery

Tags: jquery

Having two checkboxes and both having different values when I select checkbox with value `10000` in console I am always getting value `1000`

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" class="ci_check" value="1000" />1000
<input type="checkbox" name="group2[]" class="ci_check" value="10000" />10000
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".ci_check").click(function(){
    if ($('.ci_check').is(":checked")) {
        var abc = $("input[type='checkbox']").val();
        console.log(abc);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you don't select clicked element. Try this:

```
$(".ci_check").click(function(){
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
        var abc = $(this).val();
        console.log(abc);
    }
});
```

Comment: See more about [jQuery.on('click')](https://codesearchable.com/cs/4860089/)